# Eclipse - Force Refresh of IDs

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse for Android development, and the editor always seems to take a while to actually update and recognize if I change an ID in a layout, then try to use it in a class with R.id.someId. Is there a way to force a refresh?

Comment: How long is 'a while'?  Would a faster machine cure this problem? Or just slightly more patience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may be running into the delay where automatic building meets unsaved files.  Try manually saving the file after the change.
2. If you have the generated file, R.java, open in an editor then it may not update.
3. Alternately, you can blow everything away with a Project/Clean.
4. Alternately, you could manually build.
5. Highlighting the project and hitting "F5" may work for you.

Let us know what, if anything, worked for you.

Comment: Looks like a bug in strings.xml was causing the auto-build to be aborted and use old references. I'm used to working in Visual Studio, which is a tad different. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do a Project -> Clean.